# Return specific value from a list based on string value in Python

Tags: python, string, list, loops

I've retrieved presidents from the db and created a list.  Now I need to retrieve the 4 digit pin based on pname which is given by a user.  Below is the list that is generated.

```
['George Bush 6182', 'John Kennedy 5860', 'Barrack Obama 6394', 'Harry Truman 6478', 'Richard Nixon 7155']
```

I've tried looping through the list but I haven't been successful.

```
full_list = []
pName = message[cmd_index + 2]
p_map_snapshot = db_root.child('pMap').get()
p_id = p_map_snapshot[message[cmd_index + 1].lower()]
roster_snapshot = db_root.child('rosters').child(p_id).get()
print (pName)
for prez in roster_snapshot:
    full_list.append((prez['firstName'] + " " + prez['lastName'] + " " + str(prez['pinId'])))
         #LOOP HERE?
              #if pName == ?
#print(full_list)
```

Comment: Do you have some output to share ?

Comment: What's value of `pname` given by an user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to build `full_list` in the first place since you already have the names of the presidents and the corresponding PINs in a structured list of dicts `roster_snapshot`, so you can simply iterate over it and compare the given president's name with the user input, and output the PIN when they match:

```
for prez in roster_snapshot:
    if ' '.join((prez['firstName'], prez['lastName'])) == pName:
        print(prez['pinId'])
        break
```